# How do I install Cinnamon desktop environment on Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: 17.10, desktop-environments, cinnamon

I've used three terminal commands to install Cinnamon desktop environment on Ubuntu. It ran the first time I logged in, but  froze. I logged out, but there is no option to go back to Cinnamon. I tried the little gear under my login, but this did nothing. My question is how do I run the Cinnamon desktop over Ubuntu?

Comment: If possible please install 18.04. It is an LTS and it might not bug out on your login. Reason: 17.10 goes end of life on the 19th so that's in 11 days.  If not: you will need to log into a terminal session and scan the log files for errors. If you find anything include it into the question so someone can review it :)

Comment: I'm sorry kinda confused here, my ubuntu desktop works fine, just the mint has no option to even use after working once, and the one time it worked i logged in and it was there, no option to change between one desktop or the other i don't know what you mena bo log-file terminal session either. so do i just update my system?

Comment: the update fixed the desktop not showing, thanks :)